# Homotopy groups of a Bouquet of n-spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, tag-removed

Let $$X=\vee_{\alpha\in A} S_{\alpha}^n$$ be a bouquet of $n$-spheres.

Q: How does one compute the homotopy groups $\pi_k(X)$?

Comment: This is called the Hilton-Milnor theorem.  Rationally the homotopy groups are a free lie algebra with respect to the whitehead product.  Google provides you with the appropriate references.  

The result you state about the countable wedge of 2-spheres related to knot complements is false. 

Comment: To be precise, an unknot complement in $S^3$ is homeo/diffeomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb R^2$.  A countable wedge of 2-spheres has $\pi_2 X$ isomorphic to a direct sum of countable-many copies of $\mathbb Z$.  Knot complements in the 3-sphere are all $K(\pi,1)$ type spaces.  Wedges of spheres have infinitely many non-trivial homotopy groups. 

Comment: You are right completely right Ryan, I forgot the point at $\infty$,
it is the unknot complement in $\mathbf{R}^3$ which is homotopy equivalent to a countable wedge of $S^2$. I'll remove my motivation. 

Comment: The complement of the unknot in $\mathbb R^3$ is homotopy-equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^2$.   I suspect you're thinking of the *universal cover* of this space.  The universal cover of $S^1 \vee S^2$ is homotopy-equivalent to $\vee_\infty S^2$. 

Comment: @Ryan Do you mean unlink in your lower comment?

Comment: I mean the unknot. The complement of the unknot in $\mathbb R^3$ has a geometrically natural deformation retract consisting of a 2-sphere that contains the unknot (in the Jordan-Schoenflies sense) together with an arc that connects two distinct points in $S^2$. This is the arc that runs from the north pole to the south pole, through the centre of the unknot (in the sense of centroid). But this 2-complex is homotopy-equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1$, just homotope the attaching map of the arc so that the two endpoints go to the same place

Comment: The $n$-component unlink in $\mathbb R^3$ has the homotopy-type of a wedge $n$ copies of $S^2$ and $n$ copies of $S^1$.  

Comment: @Ryan, yes I meant that the complement of the unknot in $\mathbf{R}^3$
deformation retracts to $S^2\vee S^1$.